# Capybara assert element is empty

Tags: dom, testing, capybara

Looking for the best way to determine if an element is really empty.

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell One</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But both of these return `true`:

```
find("#foo td:nth-child(1)").should have_content('')
find("#foo td:nth-child(2)").should have_content('')
```

So I used this:

```
find("#foo td:nth-child(1)").text.should == 'Cell One'
find("#foo td:nth-child(2)").text.should == ''
```

Which seems to work, but doesn't check to see if the element may contain other elements. For example it may contain an image, link, or span.

I can check for each one of those individually(image, link, or span), but it seems like there should be better way.

Is there a way to test to see if the element is empty?

Comment: For your needs, is the following empty? `<td><!--- hello world --></td>`

Comment: That is a good question, but I would say no.

Comment: Simplest would probably be to just check if its innerHTML property is `""`, otherwise you can also check `.children.length===0` but that fails for the above example

Comment: Can you please give an example? As those methods are not available on a `#<Capybara::Element>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following to check that the element does not have any text and has no child elements (ie is actually empty):

```
# Has no child elements
find("#foo td:nth-child(2)").all('*').length.should == 0

# Has no text
find("#foo td:nth-child(2)").text.should==''
```

Comment: Oof.  .all("*") waits for the timeout to make sure there is nothing.

Comment: @kwerle You can pass `wait: 0` to any Finder method to stop it from waiting =) So this would be `.all("*", wait: 0)`. See allowed options in https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method